# How do I mix rounded and squared caps in a single path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

How could I mix rounded and square caps in one single path in Illustrator? For example, I need to make a rounded cap on the starting point and a square one on  its end? See the screen capture underneath.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the scissor tool to sever the path without a gap or you could create a custom pattern brush. But the way I think is the most interesting and creates the best results is adding a custom arrowhead to Illustrator.
To do this you have to find and edit Illustrators `arrowheads.ai` file.

> To define custom arrowheads, open the Arrowheads.ai file, which is located under `ShowPackageContent\Required\Resources\<locale>\` (for Mac) and `\Support Files\Required\Resources\<locale>\` (for Windows). Follow the instructions in the file to create custom arrowheads.
>   Place the updated Arrowheads.ai file at: `<Illustrator home>\Plug-ins\` and avoid replacing the existing Arrowheads.ai file.

*Source: http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stroke-object.html#customize_arrowheads*

Add an arrowhead that looks like this:

[image]

Now you access the new arrowhead in the `Stroke` menu.

Change the size of the arrowhead to fit the stroke width and change the alignment method, so the stroke tip extends beyond the end of the path.

[image]

[image]

Comment: by the way, you don't have to scale down the arrow, just draw the end of the line the save height of the line which is 1pt. and it will work perfectly.