# How do you change individual end caps in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hi I am looking to change individual end caps in Illustrator and don't seem to be able to find out how to do it or  is it not possible

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Also see here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/custom-stroke-caps-in-illustrator/36205#36205

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The appearance of the end caps is a property that is applied to a whole stroke, or not at all.

As an alternative, you could use the width tool to give a line without caps a blocky appearance on one side, and round on another.

Comment: This could be done but by using the arrow system please check the following link. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/44436/how-do-i-mix-rounded-and-squared-caps-in-a-single-path-in-illustrator

Comment: @hsawires That's more of a dupe than an alternative. Thanks for pointing it out!